# .htaccess rewrite to hide .html extension blocking access to /blog

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have an html site with 5 top-level pages, and wordpress installed as the blog in a /blog directory.  I wanted to make changes to the root .htaccess file to hide the .html extensions, and used the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

This works fine for the five .html pages, but it blocks access to the blog, resulting in a server error.

Does anyone know how I modify this rule so that it will apply to the .html files, but not to the /blog folder that is the target of the blog link.  For reference, here is the code for my top-level navigation:

```
                    <nav >
                         <ul class = "main-nav">
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. It should ignore the blog folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# ignore directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# make sure corresponding .html file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to the top of your rewrites

```
RewriteRule ^blog(/|$) - [L,NC]
```

- ^blog(/|$) matches /blog and /blog/* but wont match /blog-faq.html if you add that in the future
- The - means "do nothing"
- [L,NC] means that it's the last rule (so it doesn't look at the rules below) and that it's also case insensitive